# Saving matrix to a file (.txt format) in C

Tags: c, file, matrix

I'm having some issues trying to write a quick program which purpose is, given a matrix (bidimensional array allocated dinamically), saving it to a file. When checking the resulting output file I'm given at the end of each line of the file the following simbols, in bold and red, "\00".
This is my code:

```
   /*\param n number of rows
    \param m number of columns
    \param mat pointer to the matrix
    \param f file already opened in write mode where to write the matrix 
   */
int save_to_file (char** mat, unsigned n, unsigned m, FILE* f){

    int i, j;   

    for(i = 0;i <= n; i++)
        for(j = 0; j <= m; j++)
            if(j == m)
                fprintf(f, "%c\n", mat[i][j]);
            else
                fprintf(f, "%c", mat[i][j]);
    if (f == NULL)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Is the issue lying in the way I'm writing on the file? If that's the case, can anybody help me to fix it?

Comment: How do you allocate it? `i <=n` looks suspicious if the size is `m x n`. Also why are you chacking `f` for `NULL` after everything is done?

Comment: If any mistake has been made the function must return -1. Why does it look suspicious i <= n?

Comment: Your `for` loop executes `n+1` times (0 to `n`). I assume the dimensions of your matrix are `n x m` so that you'd want to loop 0 to `n-1` and 0 to `m-1`? In other words, use `i < n` and `j < m`. Checking for `f == NULL` when you're all done looping won't help much finding "a mistake". The check for the FILE pointer of NULL should be done before you call the function, or possibly right when you enter it. Doing `fprintf` to a valid file pointer is not going to set it to NULL on error.

Comment: Any mistake in the function will not set `f` to `NULL`. And `0` through `n` results in `n+1` iteration.

Comment: `if (f == NULL)` this test is too late, you must test if `f == NULL` even before calling  `save_to_file`, but at least before calling any `fprintf(f, ...`.

Comment: Show how you call `save_to_file` including the declaration/initialisation of all involved variables. Or even better provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

The first problem with your code is the range in the for loops. If you have `n` rows the loop must go from `0` to `n-1` (both included). So these lines:

```
for(i = 0;i <= n; i++)
    for(j = 0; j <= m; j++)
        if(j == m)
```

shall be

```
for(i = 0;i < n; i++)          // Remove =
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++)     // Remove =
        if(j == m-1)           // Insert -1
```

The second problem is that you check for `f` being `NULL` **after** you have used `f`. That is a bad idea and it may/will cause a program crash if `f` is `NULL`. Instead do the check as the first thing in the function:

```
int save_to_file (char** mat, unsigned n, unsigned m, FILE* f){
    if (f == NULL) return -1;
    ....
    ....
    return 0;
}
```

The third problem is the way you access the matrix. If your matrix is a 2D array (as you write in the text without posting the code), you can't access it correctly as a `char**`. The `char**` can be used when you have an array of char-pointers that points to arrays of chars. But not for a 2D array.

Below is an example of how the function could look for a matrix based on a 2D array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int save_to_file (unsigned n, unsigned m, char mat[n][m]){

    int i, j;   

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
            if(j == m-1)
                printf("%c\n", mat[i][j]);
            else
                printf("%c", mat[i][j]);
}

int main(void) {

    char a[2][3] = {{'a','b','c'},{'d','e','f'}};
    save_to_file(2,3,a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
abc
def
```

Notice: The above function prints to stdout instead of a file but that can be easily changed by using `fprintf`